# Is there a way to filter out unique values on one tab and have it dynamically appear in a designated column in another?

Tags: google-sheets, unique, move

***EDITED****

So I am trying to make a tab on google sheets that summarizes Google Form Data. The Data has multiple columns including a "Project Title" and "Status" columns (not next to each other).
The other tab has Different columns labeled different status'e.g., "Approved", "Denied", "Completed", etc.

See example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/1h0HaK4pSfvIYBVdzRMhfNG7bSj6SScIcqrSrZSPH_fc/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to figure out how to have the second sheet display a project based on it's most recent status, such that it should only ever appear once on the whole sheet. The first sheet is form response data, so the project, "Go Out" will appear as "Approved" and then again, eventually, as "Completed". But I don't want to see that project under both the Approved AND completed columns on the second tab - just completed (most recent). I got to the point of filtering out the titles to the correct column, but now it's making it ONLY display the most recent form response and in the correct column.

Hopefully the edit makes this a little more clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Dear @Cheryl, would you mind sharing the structure of both sheets and explain a bit more what you're trying to do? There are lots of things you can do with conditionals (if/then statements), but honestly, I don't completely understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sure. Sheet 1 has multiple columns made up by a Google form (A through L) Columns E and L are Project Title and Status Respectively. The status can be one of five options and the Project Title is unique, but can appear multiple times on this sheet. I would like to create a second sheet with the five status options as column heads and the project will populate the appropriate column as it's status changes. This would mean I would only ever see a project title once on this sheet. Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0HaK4pSfvIYBVdzRMhfNG7bSj6SScIcqrSrZSPH_fc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Google Sheet you shared and the explanations above, I believe that you'd like to list your projects in different columns, according to the 'Status' they've been assigned.

This can be done with a filter function.

```
=filter(Sheet1!E2:E,Sheet1!L2:L="Pending")
```

Simply put, this filter returns all values in Column E (E2 and downwards) on your first Sheet, as long as their matching value in Column L is 'Pending'.

In order to filter for another status like 'Completed' you only need to change the word 'Pending' to 'Completed' etc.

I've populated your sheet with some dummy data and added the filters. It would be nice if you could share the sheet publicly, so that other Stack Overflow users can have a look at it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is currently what I have in my sheets. I forgot to move the filter over to the public example. So my concern is that sheet 1 will have duplicates of one project. Some of these duplicates will move forward in status. I was wondering if there is a way to have the project only show up once on sheet 2 based on its most recent status. I can add more example projects later tonight if that clarifies things.

Comment: What you currently have in your sheets is what I wrote into your sheets. :) If you already had that before, it would have been nice if you had shared it. It also isn't clear from your question what actually should happen in case if there's a duplicate. In which of the rows should the project appear if there are multiple projects with the same name? Please flesh out your question a bit, I think it would really help.

Comment: Yeah - it's tough to explain without being able to be in front of someone with a computer. Let me go an edit the question. I do appreciate the help so far - thanks!

Comment: No worries at all! Let me rephrase my question: I understand you don't want duplicates to show up in the second sheet. But if there are duplicates, which columns take precedence over which ones? As an example: If a project is listed both as 'pending' and 'resubmit' on the first sheet, under which category should it figure in the second sheet? In the meantime an upvote of my answer would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Ideally it would be based on the timestamp of the form-response, or the most recent. but it's possible to also have a list of categories it can't be in if it's X. So Pending<Resubmit<Proactive Approval<Approval<Denied<Complete. So if a project has pending, proactive approval and approval rows, it would have to be approved because time has elapsed to negate the other two as making sense. Denied categories would only have pending or denied. But I would thinking utilizing the timestamp would be more straightforward?